# Mongo DB Database Protection

Tags: c#, database, mongodb, encryption

So Ive created a c# WPF application and I wanted to add a way for me to control who had access to it just in case the exe for it got leaked or something. So I created a MongoDB database and made a document called Password. Upon clicking the start button in the window it checks the password you've entered to the password in the database. It works perfectly fine for my uses.

However the problem presented itself when I learned about Decompilers. From what ive read my database connection link to MongoDB could be accurately decompiled. This would give the cracker access to my database with admin permissions and and would allow them to connect to it as well. What is the best way for me to prevent this from happening, and hide my secret in a way that makes it impossible/extremely to decompile?

Comment: There is no *user-mode* application security in windows, anything can be cracked and misused. One top of that, .net makes it trivially easy for any angry *school-kid* to reverse your code, and once again it doesn't really matter what you do as it can likely be circumvented. If you need security, you will need to put your sensitive information (database, services ect) behind a firewall and grant access via standard authentication and authorisation techniques

Comment: Based on your question it looks like you stored the passwords (encrypted or even as clear text) in your database. NEVER do that, store hash values. Most applications have built-in security /authentication - use these, if possible.

Comment: Ok but how do I store a hash of it while still being able to log in. Im very new to this so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Configurations and secrets including passwords should be stored outside of an application's code. Instead read secrets from a config file or via a login screen.

Comment: Hmm ok, so what file would you suggest for storing a secret that I could include alongside the exe? I'm very new to this.

Comment: You could use any number of file formats. For example `ini`, `xml`, `json`, `yaml`, etc. Use what's easiest in .NET.